# Do solids heat up on compression or extension? If so how?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential-energy, elasticity, vibrations

Well, let's take the example of a compressible solid. We know that in order to compress a solid we need to apply a force "greater(and not really equal)" than the interatomic/intermolecular repulsions that follow, more precisely, than the internal restoring force that follow. That means in the process of compressing the system from say L to l we do a little "extra" work because of the external force being a bit larger than the restoring one. So is it this "extra" work which induces thermal vibrations in the system?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109537/discussion-on-question-by-user266637-do-solids-heat-up-on-compression-or-extensi).

Comment: O!!! Thanks Friend...